# @Html.EnumDropDownListFor in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm porting an MVC5 app in ASP.NET Core.
I cannot find

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor()
```

was it deprecated and is there a substitute?
Is there any documentation where I can find all these little breaking changes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

simply use `asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof (State))"` tag helper

```
<select asp-for="State" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof (State))"></select>
```

Answer (score 37):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer, in ASP.NET 5 the functionality of EnumDropDownListFor() is obtained using DropDownListFor() in combination with  GetEnumSelectList() method. For example:

```
@model Enum
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, Html.GetEnumSelectList(Model.GetType()))
```

Note that you can decorate each value of the Enumeration with custom display names e.g. to include spaces. For instance:

```
public enum CementTypes {
    [Display(Name = "Class S")]Class_S,
    [Display(Name = "Class N")]Class_N,
    [Display(Name = "Class R")]Class_R 
}
```

Comment: With the addision of Enum as a generic constraint, GetEnumSelectList now has a generic version that makes it a bit more straight forward to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pending feature. Tracking issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/438

Comment: Thank you, can`t wait to use MVC 6!

Comment: Feature implemented and issue closed Mar 22, 2015
ASP.NET MVC Core
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
@model Enum
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(Enum)))
```